# Do we have $\mathbb{C}[\text{SL}_n] = \bigoplus_{\lambda, \,\text{ht}(\lambda)\leq n} V_{\lambda} $?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, direct-sum, invariant-theory, young-tableaux

The coordinate algebra $$\mathbb{C}[\text{SL}_n]=\mathbb{C}\big[x_{ij}: i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}\big]/\big(\det(x_{ij}) - 1\big)$$ is a representation of $\text{SL}_n$: $$(g'.f)(g)=f(g'^T g)\,.$$
Let $$V_{\lambda} = \langle e_T : T \text{ is a semistandard Young tableau of shape $\lambda$} \rangle\,,$$ where $\lambda$ is a Young diagram, $$e_T = \prod_c e_c\,,$$ where $c$ ranges over the columns of $T$, and for $c = (c_1, \ldots, c_l)^T$, $e_c$ is the minor of $x=(x_{ij})$ consisting of the first $l$ columns and rows $c_1, \ldots, c_l$. Then $V_{\lambda}$ is an irreducible representation of $\text{SL}_n$.

> Do we have $$\mathbb{C}[\text{SL}_n] = \bigoplus_{\lambda,\, \text{ht}(\lambda)\leq n} V_{\lambda}\,?$$

Let $U$ acts on $\text{SL}_n$ by right multiplication. Then $\mathbb{C}[\text{SL}_n/U]$ is generated by all minors of $x=(x_{ij})$ which uses the first $l$ columns.

> Do we have $$\mathbb{C}[\text{SL}_n/U] = \bigoplus_{\lambda,\, \text{ht}(\lambda)\leq n} V_{\lambda}\,?$$

Thank you very much.

**Edit:** Maybe the correct equalities are

(1) $\mathbb{C}[\text{SL}_n] = \bigoplus\limits_{\lambda,\, \text{ht}(\lambda)\leq n} V_{\lambda} \otimes V_{\lambda}^*$ and

(2) $\mathbb{C}[\text{SL}_n/U] = \bigoplus\limits_{\lambda,\, \text{ht}(\lambda)\leq n} V_{\lambda}$?

Maybe (1) follows from the algebraic Peter-Weyl theorem?

Comment: It would be suprising if one had equality both times (the LHSs look different). Please share your own thoughts about these questions with us. Without knowing where the questions came from and what you know already, it will be inpossible to answer the questions at the appropriate level.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, thank you very much. I have edited the post.

Comment: What you have labeled as (1) is essentially the exact statement of Peter-Weyl in this context.  What is U here? Upper triangular matrices? Upper triangular unipotent matrices?

Comment: @LJR: Do you insist on working with $\operatorname{SL}_n$ ? I have a feeling that these claims would be correct for $\operatorname{GL}_n$ (though I don't know a proof or reference, apart from a hunch that the usual suspects -- Barnabei, Brini, Rota combinatorially, Howe geometrically, Procesi algebraically -- have some work on it), but with $\operatorname{SL}_n$ the direct sums are not actually direct: e.g., the determinant should belong to $V_{\left(1^n\right)}$ and (being $=1$) to $V_{\emptyset}$ at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nate mentioned in his comment, (1) is just Peter-Weyl.  See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74758/reference-request-for-algebraic-peter-weyl-theorem) for details and references.

For (2) I assume you mean $U$ to be the unipotent radical of a Borel.  You're almost correct, it should be a direct sum over the duals
$$k[G/U] = \bigoplus V_\lambda^*$$
where $\lambda$ ranges over all irreducibles.  The way to see this is a function on $G/U$ should be a function on $G$ which is invariant under multiplication by $U$ on the left.  To see what this is, note that the Peter-Weyl decomposition is really a decomposition by $G \times G$-representations
$$k[G] = \bigoplus V_\lambda \boxtimes V_\lambda^*$$
where one $G$ acts on the left factor, the other on the right factor.  Insisting that right multiplication is $U$-invariant means taking $U$-invariant vectors of the left factor.  The only $U$-invariant of $V_\lambda$ is the highest weight vector $v_\lambda$, so we have
$$k[G/U] = \bigoplus \langle v_\lambda \rangle \otimes V_\lambda^* \simeq \bigoplus V_\lambda^*$$

Note: I might have messed up left/right and duals.  Of course duality is an involution on the category, so it's the same expression

Comment: thank you very much. Why here we use $\boxtimes$ in $V_{\lambda} \boxtimes V_{\lambda}^*$ but not $\otimes$?

Comment: If $V$ is a $G$-representation and $W$ is a $H$-representation, I write $V \boxtimes W$ to denote the corresponding $G \times H$-representation.  Contrast with the situation when $V$ is a $G$-representation and $H$ is also a $G$-representation; then $G \otimes H$ denotes a $G$-representation.  (They are isomorphic as vector spaces.)  Note that the $\boxtimes$ for representations of arbitrary associative algebras, whereas $\otimes$ only for Hopf algebras (i.e. algebras with a "diagonal map")

Comment: * $\boxtimes$ is a construction for arbitrary associated algebras, whereas $\otimes$ is only for Hopf algebras.  (In fact, to define $\otimes$ for Hopf algebras, one uses $\boxtimes$ to get a $A \otimes A$ representation, then restricts using the diagonal map to get a $A$-representation.

Comment: ** actually, the $\otimes$ operation doesn't really require a Hopf algebra structure, just a coalgebra structure, i.e. a comultiplication $A \rightarrow A \otimes A$.  When $A = kG$ for $G$ finite this is given by the diagonal group homomorphism.